# Wordpress "get_post_meta" - I cant echo it

Tags: wordpress

I cant echo the get_post_meta in my html select field.

get_the_id and get_the_title are working fine. Why does "get_post_meta" not work?

```
<select id="the_event" name="the_event" data-required="no" data-type="select">

<option value="-1">Termine</option>


<?php // WP_Query arguments

$args = array(

'post_type' => array( 'venue' ),

'post_status' => array( 'published' ),

'order' => 'ASC',

'orderby' => 'title',

);

// The Query

$i_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $i_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $i_query->have_posts() ) {

$i_query->the_post();

?>

<option value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?> / <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'venue_ort', true ); ?>
</option>
<?php 
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

</select>
```

Any suggestion how I can echo the get_post_meta?

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump()` to see what's actually being returned?

Comment: @DenisCGN you have a missing `}` ending of `if` condition

Comment: Thanks a lot! it was the missing } And I used the wrong meta name :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try using below loop and see if that helps.

Also make sure you have created field in wp-dashboard

```
<?php
   $type = 'venue';
   $args = array(
   'post_type' => $type,
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'order' => 'ASC',
       'orderby' => 'title'
       );
       $my_query = null;
       $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  ?>
    <div>
        <?php if( $my_query->have_posts() ):?>
          <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <p>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'venue_ort', true); ?>
                </p>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to closed if condition `}`

Please check below code : 
Correct code :

```
<select id="the_event" name="the_event" data-required="no" data-type="select">

<option value="-1">Termine</option>


<?php // WP_Query arguments

$args = array(

'post_type' => array( 'venue' ),

'post_status' => array( 'published' ),

'order' => 'ASC',

'orderby' => 'title',

);

// The Query

$i_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $i_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $i_query->have_posts() ) {

$i_query->the_post();

?>

<option value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?> / <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'venue_ort', true ); ?>
</option>
<?php 
}
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

</select>
```

I have checked on my site. It is working now: http://prntscr.com/p3rua6

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I used the wrong mega field name :-(

Comment: It's my pleasure  @DenisCGN

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! I used the wrong meta name. I did not realize that the plugin uses a prefix for the field. It is ptb_venue_ort. With that name it works like charm!
Denis